# Maven repo missing jars for hbase package - but works fine for others such as hbase-common/client/etc)

Tags: maven, hbase

The following hbase artifacts from maven work JUST FINE including the sources:

```
hbase-client
hbase-common
hbase-server
hbase-shell
hbase-examples
hbase-thrift
hbase-protocol
```

Here is an example of the repo for hbase-common that contains all the correct artifacts:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-common/0.96.1.1-hadoop1

HOWEVER the

```
hbase    (base package)
```

does NOT work.

I tried two different versions:

- 0.9.6.1.1-hadoop1
- 0.98.3-hadoop1

I get the following errors:

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.hbase#hbase;0.98.3-hadoop1!hbase.jar (0ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.98.3-hadoop1/hbase-0.98.3-hadoop1.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.hbase#hbase;0.98.3-hadoop1!hbase.jar(src) (129ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.98.3-hadoop1/hbase-0.98.3-hadoop1-sources.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.hbase#hbase;0.98.3-hadoop1!hbase.jar
[warn]  :: org.apache.hbase#hbase;0.98.3-hadoop1!hbase.jar(src)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Notice: there are NO jar files here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.96.1.1-hadoop1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "base" package does not exist in 0.95+.  The classes I was searching for were contained in hbase-server.jar